# How to call an API behind Azure AD authentication in Azure WebApps?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have a WebApp deployed in Azure App Service and enabled azure ad authentication.

Now we need to call an API from another application programmatically.

How can we acquire the AD token to call this API ? As we cant pass credentials directly we need to acquire token.

I am aware that incase of any front end application like angular or react we can use msadal library to request for the token and it redirects to Microsoft login and come back with token.

How can we achieve this incase of a server requesting the same API ?

Note:
We have the generic user id in azure ad for this purpose.

Thanks,
Mahesh B

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, use `Azure.Identity` package to use your Service Principle (or Managed Identity etc) to acquire a `TokenCrendential`

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#credentials

Comment: I think this approach works only within the Azure context. What if we need to access it from a different cloud or a vm ?

Comment: if you are using a service principle, you can use that from anywhere

Comment: And if you are using an Azure VM, also Managed Identity are available and should be the preferred way then